# Three different tables (sql) show like one content

Tags: php, sql, datetime

My question is simple. How to show content from three tables on one page together ordered by date.

It's a blog where i have posts like Articles, Statuses and Quotes.

**ARTICLE - Id, Title, Photo, Text, Type, Datetime (php - time())**

**STATUS - Id, Title, Text, Type, Datetime (php - time())**

**QUOTE - Id, Quote, Author, Type, Datetime (php - time())**

I need to show the content on page ordered by **Datetime**. Then i can change the html/css by Type of post.

It'll be better to Join tables or show it in Array?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the sorting in the MySQL you need to unify fields from three tables and do UNION ALL, not JOIN. 
You can use join when you have some relation between three, as far as I can see those tables are not related.

Other option for you is to merge results from those three queries in an array.

```
$merged = array();

foreach($articles as $k => $article){
    $merged[$article['Datetime']] = array('table' => 'articles', 'id' => $k);
}
foreach($statuses as $k => $statuse){
    $merged[$statuse['Datetime']] = array('table' => 'statuses', 'id' => $k);
}foreach($quotes as $k => $quote){
    $merged[$quote['Datetime']] = array('table' => 'quotes', 'id' => $k);
}

ksort($merged);

foreach ($merged as $key => $value)
{
    $arr = $$value['table'];
    echo $arr[$value['id']]; 
}
```

Of course you can do some refactoring but this snippet shows in short how you can do it.

Comment: Thank you so MUCH! I learned from your Php script something new but i created it with the Sql. I didn't listen about UNION ALL never before. It's so simple now. :)

Comment: I have one more question. Please if i want to load everything in this UNION ALL sql,  it's impossible to show cols that are not the same in all tables. How can i get this content without more sqls?

Comment: This should help what do you think? SELECT column 1, column 2, '' AS 'column 3' FROM table a
UNION  
SELECT column 1, column 2, column 3 FROM table b

Answer (score 1):

You may try this query..but I have made assumption that Type is common in all three tables

```
SELECT a.Id,a.Title,a.Photo,a.Text,
a.Type,a.DateTime,s.Title,s.Text,q.Quote,q.Author,q.Type
FROM ARTICLE  a
INNER JOIN STATUS s
ON a.Type = b.Type
INNER JOIN QUOTE q
ON b.Type = q.Type
GROUP BY a.Type
ORDER BY a.Datetime ASC;
```

If type is not giving result then use id in "ON" condition
 Because,table structure is not defined proprly in question.

Comment: Thank you for answer, i know that i didn't defined more things in my question. The type is 1,2 or 3. Every type of post has different type for different html/css style. :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who will searching for simmilar solution i created it this simple way:

```
SELECT id, datetime FROM article
UNION ALL
SELECT id, datetime FROM status
UNION ALL
SELECT id, datetime FROM quote
ORDER BY datetime ASC;
```

Now i know the ID's of posts and can show everything sorted by datetime.